# What features are enterprise and what are free when looking at user guide?

Tags: magento2

Is visual merchandiser in magento 2 community edition?

I'm learning magento and while reading documentation trying to find how to do something, I'll see things like visual merchandiser and I'm unable to find that same feature in my 2.2.5 installation by following the instructions.

Is there a way to see what is enterprise only when looking at user docs? Even this doc says "Magento Commerce"

Comment: Magento Commerce = Enterprise. Magento OpenSource = Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Marius in comments, in the upper right hand of page it will say:

- "Magento Open Source
  " if its a free, open-source feature.
- It will say "Magento Commerce " if it's
  Enterprise/paid.

Note that the URL of results you end up at when googling for documentation will be different too:

- Open-source: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/...
- Enterprise: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/...

[image]

[image]